# Can’t remember model of bike, recently stolen

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image]I recently just had my bike stolen can’t seem to remember the model nor name of the bike.., I don’t have the serial code or anything.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Is this the only picture you have?  It doesn't show any badges or decals.  That said, it doesn't look like a very valuable bike; is there a particular reason to have the model of this bike, as opposed to a replacement?

Comment: It's terrible having a bike stolen. It's even more terrible when you find out that chances are low of ever getting it back. You do have a picture so that if the police do find it the bike you can claim it. I wish the best for you.

Comment: I’d get a new bike but this bike is particularly special due to the fact it was the first bike my cousin learned to ride on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a blue/turquoise painted BMX.  The bike has grinding pegs on both the front and rear axles, so it was set up more as a "trick" or stunt BMX over racing or riding.

Curiously, the one brake lever visible goes off in the direction of the back wheel, and I see no trace of a front brake at all.  There is also no detangler which means the bike can't do bar spins.

This suggests that it was not a "proper" high-end tricks bike, and was more likely a generic kid's BMX.

I'm sorry that your bike was stolen.  And now you either pay for a replacement or struggle with insurance to get a payout which could end up being less than you need for a replacement bike, and may end up costing more than any payout by the time all the clauses are evaluated.

You can try sending the above photo to pawn shops in your area too.  I managed to get a stolen digital camera recovered by doing this.   Also doing a police report for stolen property will be required for the insurance claim.

Comment: End of the answer seems to be cut off!

Comment: Yes, i found the back brakes kinda rubbed against the back tire.. i tried fixing it and yea i pretty much said fuck it and gave up lol. 
The reason I don’t wanna give this bike up because it was the first bike my lil cousin learned to ride on.

Comment: @MaplePanda thanks - not sure what happened there.

Comment: @CheyenneLouiseGamache sentimental reasons are a totally valid thing.  But don't dwell on what-was when you can go make some new memories too.  Take lil'cuz to a MTB space and make some more memories.

Comment: And not only that’d I’d file it to the police but they won’t do shit cause my town cops are lazy and dumb as fuck, like someone broke into my friends house they had video proof and you can see their face clearly on camera and the cops said.. not enough proof sorry we can’t do anything about it..!! LIKE BRO WE HAD VIDEO PROOF?!

Comment: It’s whatever I’ll probably get a better higher quality bmx, I’ve been looking at this one for awhile.. so I might say fuck it and just buy it. 

Comment: @CheyenneLouiseGamache take precautions with any replacement.  There's a chance they'll come back in the future, so lock it or store it inside, or both.   Cameras are deterrents at best.  Invest in locks and use them.

Comment: Yea I will in future, learnt my lesson Man.